# UITable with UILabel or else?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Following image is using UILable or else ? When I use UILabel , textcolor is black and text color is not change when I selected. So, I think, it's not UILabel. How to write like that ?
[image]

Another question is how to write option table like following.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a UILabel with a bluish textColor.  Try UITableViewCellStyleValue1.

The second has UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark.